# Is that two commutative elliptic isometry have at least one same fixed point？

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry, discrete-geometry

I am reading the hyperbolic geometry by Martelli's book 《An Introduction to Geometry Topology》, the question is from p136 proposition 5.1.4's proof  $ (3)  \Rightarrow  ( 4 ) $, it ask me to adapting the proof of lemma 4.2.1: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEAIP.png)

So if $\varphi_1 $ and $\varphi_2$ is all isometry in $\mathsf{Isom}(\mathbb{H^n}) $ or some model, i think it can't be $\varphi_1 \varphi_2=\varphi_2 \varphi_1\Rightarrow \mathsf{Fix}  \varphi_1 = \mathsf{Fix}  \varphi_1$, I think it shoud be $\varphi_1 \varphi_2=\varphi_2 \varphi_1\Rightarrow \mathsf{Fix}  \varphi_1 \cap \mathsf{Fix}  \varphi_1 \neq \varnothing$

But I really dont know how to prove that, I have proved in $\mathsf{Isom}(\mathbb{H^2}) $, because it have only one fixed point ,but in higher dimension, the elliptic type have at least one, even infinity(I am not sure).

I have try in the direction of the order of elliptic is finite, but I dont know what can it bring me, I ongly can write $\mathsf{Fix}  \varphi_1$ into $\{\varphi_2 x_1,....,\varphi_2^n 
 x_1,\varphi_2 x_2,....,\varphi_2^n x_2,......\} $, which the order of $\varphi_2$ is n.

Comment: Hint: Assuming that $\phi_1, \phi_2$ commute, prove that $\phi_1$ preserves the fixed-point set of $\phi_2$ and vice-versa. Then study the geometry of the fixed-point sets and see how each fixed point of, say, $\phi_1$ yields a fixed-point set of $\phi_1$ on $Fix(\phi_1)$. Lastly, proofread your questions before posting.

Comment: @ 
Moishe Kohan
  thank you，now i know how to prove that, the point is barycenter is be fixed ,that means i need to pick only one point in my last set, but i am wondering what should i proofread before i  before posting, i dont see any problem in my posting

Comment: Do you know that a sentence in English always starts with an upper case letter and ends with a punctuation mark (typically, .)? Do you know that a space is always required after each punctuation mark? Do you know that the word "I" is always capitalized? Etc.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really know all of this, and I have corrected what you said, thank you for your point out.